# Is there a such thing as an operator of operators in mathematics?

Tags: operator-theory

Thus far I have seen operators of numbers and operators that perform on functions like Laplace, Fourier and Z-Transforms but is there an operator in existence that performs on other operators?

Like a trasform of a transform so to speak?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the automorphism group of an operator group.

Comment: How is an operator different from a function?

Comment: I know what you mean @rschwieb and the answer is an operator is a function just as a transform is a function of functions. Perhaps I mean a transform of transforms.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I think that is what Im looking for.

Comment: @Nirma I think you are under the impression that there is a careful naming scheme for using words like "transform" and "operator." There isn't, really. They are all just functions, and functions can have any sets for their domain and codomains. The only reason we bring in special words like "transform" "homomorphism" and "operator" is partially so that we're not using just "function" all the time and partially disciplinary custom.

Comment: @Nirma For example "linear function" and "linear transformation" and "linear map" all mean the same thing in linear algebra. Some people might add "linear operator" to that list (but I'm not sure.) In category theory, there are things called transformations that are like functions but their domains and codomains are proper [classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_class), but for practical purposes they are still just "functions."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at some of the hits from a google search for ["exponentiation of operators"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22exponentiation+of+operators%22&oq=%22). Among other things, you'll see that exponentials of various differentiation operators, e.g. $e^{\frac{d}{dx}}$, arise in quantum mechanics. More general than exponentiation of operators are operators of operators defined by various power series expansions of an operator.

Also, searches for [*operator algebras*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22operator+algebras%22), and especially for [*maps on operator algebras*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22maps+on+operator+algebras%22), will bring up things you're looking for. Below are a couple of examples I found without looking very deep into these searches:

Robert T. Moore, [*Exponentiation of operator Lie algebras on Banach spaces*](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1965-71-06/S0002-9904-1965-11437-9/S0002-9904-1965-11437-9.pdf), **Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society** 71 #6 (November 1965), 903-908.

Jinchuan Hou and Jianlian Cui, [*Additive maps on standard operator algebras preserving invertibilities or zero divisors*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379502004196), **Linear Algebra and its Applications** 359 #1−3 (January 2003), pp. 219−233.