# Generalizing a function that operates on functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, smooth-functions

I've not studied much beyond Calculus so my notation and terminology may be rough/incorrect.
I've got a 'function' $\mathfrak F$ that uses other functions and goes like this:
$$
    \mathfrak F(f,n) = D_x^nf \\
    f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R \\
    n \in \Bbb Z
$$
Some examples:
$$
    f(x) = x^2 \\
    \mathfrak F(f,2) = D_x^2x^2 = 2 \\
    \mathfrak F(f,-3)= D_x^{-3}x^2 = \frac{1}{60}x^5 + \frac{C_1}{2}x^2+C_2x+C_3
$$
My questions are:
1. What's the proper notation for this?
2. How can I write this so that $n \in \Bbb R$ or even $n \in \Bbb C$?
3. How can I write this so that $f$ is multi-variable?
Finally,
4. Would this 'function' be differentiable along $n$ ($n \in \Bbb R$)?

Comment: I believe what you're looking at is commonly referred to as a *differential operator*. There's more written about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator

Comment: @desiigner Ah, I believe you're right! But, can we make the order of the operator to be a Real or Complex number? Can we then take a sort of derivative of the operator with respect to the order?

Comment: @CaseyMalessa I believe you're looking for the [differintegral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differintegral).

Comment: @eyeballfrog That seems like the right direction! Thank you, I'll have to look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your notation is fine, but incomplete in two ways. Firstly you have not specified a domain and a codomain for the operator $\mathscr{F}$. For the domain we can take the smooth functions $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(X,Y)$, where $X$, $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ are open.
   However, for negative $n$ this will not work for the codomain, as the constants you introduce do not specify a unique smooth function. Hence you need to make a *choice* of constants here to make things uniform. For instance you could set them all to zero. Secondly $\mathscr{F}(f,n) \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(X,Y)$ is a function. Consequently one should write $\big(\mathscr{F}(f,n)\big)(x)$ if you specify with a variable $x$ on the right hand side.
2. This has been extensively studied under the slogan [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus). One way of defining those things is to use Fourier-Transformations, which turn differentiation into multiplication operators. Then one only has to understand exponentiation by complex numbers, which itself is not completely harmless. To make all operations well defined, one usually restricts oneself to a smaller function space than $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(X,Y)$, such as the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). The latter is nice, because the Fourier-Transform is an isomorphism of the Schwartz space. Note that this is not the only way of doing about extending the
3. Generalizing all of the above to higher dimensions, i. e. more variables, is straightforward by the use of [multiindex notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiindex). Typically the additional bookkeeping turns out to be harder than the mathematical generalizations needed.
4. Talking about smoothness requires [differentiable structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_structure) on the domain and codomain of your operator. The involved function spaces are infinite dimensional, but can be given the structure of a [Fréchet manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_manifold). As the other answer stated, you should look into the notion of Differential operators for more about this. Note that there is quite a bit of differential geometry and functional analysis involved at this stage. And to your question: I do not know, but I assume one could *define* a fractional calculus by smooth extension of the involved operators after defining them for $n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Casey Malessa: You might also find the following of interest: [Is there a such thing as an operator of operators in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372429/13130)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro That is interesting. Honestly, I don't even know how to interpret $e^\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}$ right now. I'll have to look into all this a lot more.

Comment: @Casey Malessa: Don't worry about it being too weird to comprehend, because **it is weird**, but eventually you'll get used to it, at least if at some future time you wind up working with it a lot. This is in fact the case for many things in mathematics, such as fractional (and even complex number) values of a dimension, different kinds of infinity (even different kinds of infinity for "geometric" dimensions), [everything can be built from nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe), [the Banach-Tarski Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox), etc.