# A twist to the definition of a derivative

Tags: derivatives, definition

Two questions:

1. Functions are connections between numbers. Derivatives are connections between functions. So is there something like connections between derivatives?
2. What function does the following limit yield:
   $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}  \frac{ f' (x)- f' (a)}{f(x)-f(a)}$$
   (for example if we plug in $\sin(x),$ then we get $- \tan(x),$ and if we plug in $x^{2},$ then we get  $\frac{1}{x} $)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: 1. What do you mean exactly by "connections"? 2. Use the L'Hôpital Rule.

Comment: Input and output

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%28Zeta%27%5Bx%5D+-+Zeta%27%5Ba%5D%29%2F%28Zeta%5Bx%5D+-+Zeta%5Ba%5D%29%2C+x+-%3E+a%5D) in  the case of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Derivatives are also functions as such, so you can "connect" them to other "derivatives" just by differentiation (or integration, if you prefer).

Comment: I you do that derivative process over and over to a general function, you should arrive at a ratio of binomial sums. https://oeis.org/A002193

Comment: What if you consider multiplication by $1,$ where $1 = \frac{x-a}{x-a}?$ Then, rearrange the fractions to generalize the solution in the link provided by Mats Granvik?

Comment: A derivative is something called an operator, so you are asking if there is an operator of operators

Comment: Relevant is the Wikipedia article [Differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) and the MSE question [Generalizing a function that operates on functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3331063/13130). @Buraian: Possibly of interest: [Is there a such thing as an operator of operators in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372429/13130)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function such that $$Y(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{f(x)-f(a)}$$ exists and is a real number. Since $f$ is differentiable at $a$, we find that
\begin{eqnarray}
Y(a)\cdot f'(a) &=& \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{f(x)-f(a)}\cdot \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\\
&=& \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{x-a}\\
&=& f''(a).
\end{eqnarray}
So for twice differentiable functions such that $Y(a)$ exists and such that $f'(a)\neq 0$, we find that $Y=\frac{f''(a)}{f'(a)}$. This gives a nice answer as to what this limit actually is for this class of functions. Alternatively, you can use l'Hôpitals rule to calculate this limit as suggested by Ultralegend5385 in the comments.

Now note that if $f(x)=c$ is a constant function, then $Y(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{0}{f(x)-f(a)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{0}{0}$ does not exists as we cannot divide by zero. So the requirement that $Y(a)$ exists is not satisfied for all twice differentiable functions. It becomes even trickier for functions like $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}x^n\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \mbox{ if }x\neq 0,\\ 0 & \mbox{ if } x=0\end{cases}$$ to figure out whether $Y(0)$ even exists. All in all, I'd say it's not the most interesting limit to look at.