# Function that returns a function

Tags: functions, notation

Is there a notation for a function that returns another function? Maybe something like $f(x) = (y) = y + x$ i.e. the function being returned would return it's input plus $x$, e.g. $f(2)(3) = 5$?

Is the way I have written it correct?

Comment: When you say "returns" you are probably thinking about programming. That's a different story. In math terms, you of course can have a function which takes values in a set of functions.

Comment: You might be interested in the Wikipedia article on [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Comment: Often a "function defined on functions" is called an operator. For example, there is the differentiation operator on the set of polynomial functions. The branch of mathematics that is probably most closely connected with this notion is [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis). In fact, there are even natural examples of [operators defined on operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/372564/13130).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of functions $\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$. If I'm understanding you correctly, what you're talking about is a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \mathcal{F}$, such that for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$, $f(x)\in \mathcal{F}$ is that function $\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ such that for all $\alpha\in \Bbb{R}$, we have
\begin{align}
[f(x)](\alpha):= \alpha + x
\end{align}

A slightly quicker way of writing this is that for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
f(x):= (\Bbb{R}\ni \alpha \mapsto \alpha + x)
\end{align}

Or yet another way of writing this is: $f:\Bbb{R}\to \mathcal{F}$,
\begin{align}
x\mapsto (\alpha \mapsto \alpha + x)
\end{align}
In words, this is saying that $f$ is that function which maps an element $x\in \Bbb{R}$ to the function $\alpha\mapsto \alpha + x$ from $\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$.

---

So, yes we have $[f(2)](3) = 2+3 = 5$. If you want to be slightly more economical with your bracketing then sure $f(2)(3) = 5$ is also true. But if you're ever writing this stuff down for someone else to read then make sure you write "$f:\Bbb{R}\to \mathcal{F}$" before hand to avoid any misunderstanding. Because if you don't say anything before hand then people will automatically assume that $f$ is itself a function $\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ so when they see $f(2)(3)$ they'll either think this is weird notation/ a typo/ a multiplication of $(f(2)) \cdot (3) = 3 \cdot f(2)$, which is of course not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a notation for a function that returns another function?

Yes, lambda notation can be used to define a function that returns another function.

Example. The function that takes as an argument a natural number N, and returns the function $x^N$ can be written as

$$\lambda N . \lambda x . x^N$$

To apply this function it is best to first give it a name

$$f = \lambda N . \lambda x . x^N$$

Then to apply it to two arguments you would write

$$f(2)(\pi)$$

exactly as in your question. The result will be $\pi^2$

However, it is not *necessary* that you give the function a name. You can also use the lambda expression "anonymously".

$$(\lambda N . \lambda x . x^N)(2)(\pi)$$

means exactly the same thing.

A function whose range is a set of functions is called a higher-order function.