# Logical extension of exponential function?

Tags: logic, exponential-function

I’ve been thinking a lot about logical extensions of the exponential function, i.e. one for multiplication and addition (and maybe  even one for tetration?)

We know (almost by definition) that:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\log_e\left(a\right)x\right)^{i}}{i!}=a^x
$$

And I discovered:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{ax}{e}\right)i}{i!}=ax
$$

However:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a+x-e\right)+i}{i!}\neq a+x
$$

Can anyone think of another logical extension from the exponential function?  Whether for multiplication or for addition?

Thanks!

Post script:
I also discovered this:
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a+x-e\right)+i}{i!}}{e}+e-1=a+x
$$
though this is certainly less elegant and doesn’t appear to be a logical extension.

Comment: Of possible interest is my [30 January 2006 sci.math post "*Is e^x zero in some extended number system?*](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/9vm2VdMTuQw/m/CbxnUYirGakJ)" and its [same-day follow-up](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/9vm2VdMTuQw/m/PDLbBgebnfwJ). However, I know almost nothing about the kind of generalization discussed there. The paper I excerpt from is Paul Dienes, [*The exponential function in linear algebras*](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/os-1.1.300), **Quarterly Journal of Mathematics** (Oxford) 1 (1930), 300-309

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Definitely interesting. though I can’t claim I understood much of it.  I’m also not entirely sure how it’s related...

Comment: There's also the notion of exponentiation of an operator (an operator being a function in which "ordinary functions" are the inputs and outputs, such as the differentiation operator), and things like $e^{\frac{d}{dx}}$ actually play an important role in quantum mechanics. See also my answer to [Is there a such thing as an operator of operators in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/372564/13130)

Comment: So you have $f_a(x)\in\{a^x,a\cdot x,a+x\}$ and you write $$f_e(f_e^{-1}(f_a(x))=f_a(x)$$ while using Taylor expansion for $e$, then you rewrite RHS to put (almost) everything under the sum? And your question is, "Can anyone think of another way to rewrite RHS?" ?

Comment: @Vepir No, my question is: Why, logically, doesn’t the third equation in my post work, and what would logically make it work.  I will stress, I don’t mean Mathematically, as I have a Mathematical solution, I mean logically.

Comment: The fact that multiplication is distributive over addition is what makes the second equation work and is what makes the third equation fail.