# More abstract mathematical operator than PI and SIGMA

Tags: functions

I have been going down the YouTube mathematics rabbit hole. I learned about something called Willans' (horribly inefficient) formula for calculating the *nth* prime, which made use of the Sigma (summation) operator, as well as some other axioms, and the floor function.

Then I watched a video about extending the definition of *factorial!* to the real numbers, which makes use of the Pi (product) operator.

Then it hit me. Is there a more abstract operator than Pi and Sigma, one which takes a binary function as an additional parameter? Say for example, Omega. Omega((+)) would then equal Sigma, and Omega((*)) would equal Pi. I was curious if there exists a higher order operator like this in formal mathematics.

To somewhat answer my own question, I have dabbled quite a bit in Haskell programming. In Haskell, there are two *folding* functions, *foldl* and *foldr*, which do something similar, except folds in Haskell operate on foldable data structures rather than a function and a range.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How would it be any different than assigning two random new symbols to $\displaystyle\sum$ and $\displaystyle\prod$?

Comment: @insipidintegrator it would take one additional parameter: a binary function. I guess it might be a stupid question but I was just curious so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: In programming this would be reduce(). Of course it is not a problem to define something like this formally in math but the question is why? $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ are notational shorthands, just like $\bigoplus$, $\bigcup$, $\bigcap$ and many others used in the same way.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation

Comment: @Michael thank you for your comment. It's full of insight. I can't imagine in what case such an operator would be useful. Reading the formal definition on Wikipedia, I see that a "default" value would have to be supplied, e.g. 1 for multiplication or 0 for addition, in cases where b < a. I thought maybe such an operator would be useful so less language would be needed to express ideas in math, but I see that this might just be too abstract, and cause more confusion than concision, to have a legitimate place in formal mathematics. I was just wondering if it exists.

Comment: *if there exists a higher order operator like this in formal mathematics* --- I'm not sure whether you're asking a question related to programming/CS issues (of which I would know almost nothing about) or a question about a mathematical issue. If the latter, then certainly functions can have other functions as inputs. Even in a school-level first calculus course one can make the observation that taking the derivative of a (differentiable) function is itself a function. **(continued)**

Comment: Moreover, even in applied fields (such as quantum mechanics) the notion of a function whose input can be the operation of taking the derivative (among other possibilities) is used. For more about this, see my answer to [Is there a such thing as an operator of operators in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/372564/13130).