# Is there an operation of the type $([0,1]\to\text{real})\to(([0,1]\to\text{real})\to\text{real})\to (([0,1]\to\text{real})\to\text{real})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, type-theory

In the introduction of the book lambda calculus with types by Barendregt, there are examples of typed functions like
[image]

And I wonder what operation the underlined type expression is for.

Although we can surely make an operation of the type, I want to find the real example in functional analysis that the author was thinking about.

The cited book is Lax, *Functional Analysis*.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in trying to untangle this at the moment, but maybe some of the possibilities in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/372564/13130) will work, or can be adjusted to work, or at least indicate other possibilities.

Comment: The underlined type seems to be of the form $() \rightarrow () \rightarrow ()$.  Do we have to know a certain convention about how this is associated?

Comment: Yes. In this area, it is usually right-associative. So the function takes two arguements. (Or if the rightmost parenthesis is discarded, it takes three arguements.)